# When does a Postgres extension consume memory?

Tags: postgresql

I am wondering when a Postgres extension is increasing the memory footprint of my server.
Is memory consumption already increased when I install the extension or do I need to load the extension first with `CREATE EXTENSION $some-extension;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends somewhat on the extension.

Installing the software will only create some files and not bind any memory.

Typically, `CREATE EXTENSION` does nothing except create the database objects that belong to the extension. That will only contribute to memory usage by adding a little to the database metadata that are cached in each database session. Usually, that is negligible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was my assumption and after installing some extension on the docker postgres container I did not see anything increase.